# Kotlin - how to parse a string that is either in a LocalDateTime or LocalDate format into LocalDate

Tags: kotlin, datetime

I have a mapper where I am getting a string that is either in this format:

```
"2021-06-08" or "2021-06-08T15:00"
```

in my mapper I should convert this string always into a `LocalDate`:

```
ExcelColumn.CHANGED_DATE -> rowData
        .nullLocalDate(column.dbColumnName)
        ?.format(excelV2DateFormat)
```

`nullLocalDate` looks like this:

```
 fun Entity.nullLocalDate(key: String): LocalDate? = if (this[key] == null) null else localDate(key)

 fun Entity.localDate(key: String): LocalDate = when (val v = this[key]) {
   is LocalDateTime -> v.toLocalDate()
   is Instant -> LocalDate.ofInstant(v, ZoneId.of("UTC"))
   is String -> LocalDate.parse(v)
   else -> v as LocalDate
 }
```

I also have a function that checks `nullLocalDateTime`:

```
fun Entity.nullLocalDateTime(key: String): LocalDateTime? = if (this[key] == null) null else localDateTime(key)

fun Entity.localDateTime(key: String, zoneId: ZoneId? = null): LocalDateTime = when (val v = this[key]) {
  is Instant -> LocalDateTime.ofInstant(v, zoneId ?: ZoneId.of("UTC"))
  is String -> LocalDateTime.parse(v)
  else -> v as LocalDateTime
}
```

I can use one or the other, but how can I combine this two to check if it is either in localDate or localDateTime format and convert it into localDate in both cases?
As of now it works fine if the value is in format `"2021-06-08"`, but it fails if the string is in the format of `"2021-06-08T15:00"`:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-06-08T15:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
```

How can I accommodate both cases in one function?

Comment: Why are you not using a `DateTimeFormatter`? This should be easily parseable with the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd['T'HH:mm]`. Did I miss something?

Comment: I am not sure in what way should I use this, this will always return the same format as it gets ie.  2021-06-08T15:00 for 2021-06-08T15:00 and 2021-06-08 for 2021-06-08, and I need 2021-06-08 in both cases. @Sweeper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define optional parts in the pattern of a `DateTimeFormatter`. In your case, you'd want:

```kotlin
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd['T'HH:mm]")
```

Where the `['T'HH:mm]` defines the optional time part. You can then use this formatter when parsing your strings into `LocalDate` instances. There are a few ways this can be done, but the easiest and most readable is to use the `LocalDate#parse(CharSequence,DateTimeFormatter)` method.

Runnable example:

```kotlin
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

fun main() {
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd['T'HH:mm]")

    val dateOnlyString = "2021-06-08"
    val dateAndTimeString = "2021-06-08T15:00"

    val parsedDateOnly = LocalDate.parse(dateOnlyString, formatter)
    val parsedDateAndTime = LocalDate.parse(dateAndTimeString, formatter)

    println("parse(\"$dateOnlyString\") --> $parsedDateOnly")
    println("parse(\"$dateAndTimeString\") --> $parsedDateAndTime")
}
```

Output:

```
parse("2021-06-08") --> 2021-06-08
parse("2021-06-08T15:00") --> 2021-06-08
```

Answer (score 1):

One more option:

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd['T'HH:mm]")
val dt = formatter.parseBest(str, LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from)
```

Here `dt` will be instance of LocalDateTime or LocalDate (depending on the `str` input string).

Note, that you cannot parse input with format "yyyy-MM-dd" into LocalDateTime, even if you use optional parts in the DateTimeFormatter pattern.

Comment: Another option is to use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder::parseDefaulting`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting(java.time.temporal.TemporalField,long)) when building the formatter. Though depending on what exactly you're trying to do, `parseBest` may be the better option.